# Build jsonb array from jsonb field

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have column `options` with type jsonb ,  in format `{"names": ["name1", "name2"]}` which was created with

```
UPDATE table1 t1 SET options = (SELECT jsonb_build_object('names', names) FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.id= t1.id)
```

and where `names` have type jsonb array.

`SELECT jsonb_typeof(names) FROM table2` give `array`

Now I want to extract value of `names` as jsonb array. But query

```
SELECT jsonb_build_array(options->>'names') FROM table
```

gave me `["[\"name1\", \"name2\"]"]`, while I expect `["name1", "name2"]`

How can I get value in right format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `->>` operator will return the value of the field (in your case, a JSON array) as a properly escaped text. What you are looking for is the `->` operator instead.

However, note that using the `jsonb_build_array` on that will return an array containing your original array, which is probably not what you want either; simply using `options->'names'` should get you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you don't need to use `jsonb_build_array()` function.

Use `select options -> 'names' from table;` This will fix your issue.

`jsonb_build_array()` is for generating the array from `jsonb` object. You are following wrong way. That's why you are getting string like this `["[\"name1\", \"name2\"]"]`.

Try to execute this sample SQL script:

```
select j->'names'
from (
  select '{"names": ["name1", "name2"]}'::JSONB as j
) as a;
```